# Why am I getting segmentation fault using strcmp?

Tags: c, cs50

My program should print out "Not found" not "Segmentation fault", what's happening here?

This is my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string names[] = {"Bill", "Charlie", "Fred", "George", "Ginny", "Percy", "Ron"};

    for (int i = 0; 1 < 7; i++)
   {
      if(strcmp(names[i], "Angle") == 0 )
      {
          printf("Found\n");
          return 0;
      }
   }
   printf("Not found\n");
   return 1;
}
```

I complied the program with make and when I ran it, I got "Segmentation fault". So confused...

Comment: Hint: You have a typo in `for (int i = 0; 1 < 7; i++)` causing it to turn into an infinite loop.  You crash with a Segmentation Fault when you read off the end of the `names` array.

Comment: `1 < 7` - this is why using `i` for variable is not recommended.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good luck getting the whole industry to stop.

Comment: @Barmar One can start from themselves. `ii` works ok

Comment: Please add the `cs50` tag in future questions (during your course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop will stop when `1 < 7` is no longer true.

`1` will ***always*** be less than `7`.
Your loop will never end.

In the meantime, variable `i` will get incremented everytime through the loop.  While `i` has values `0` to `6`, that is not a problem.  But once `i` is value `7` and greater, then `names[i]` is *undefined*, and can reference any memory, including invalid memory.

You might get "lucky" and accessing `names[7]`, `names[8]`, `names[9]` might not segfault... but sooner or later in your infinite loop, a Segfault will occur.

To fix this problem, re-consider when your loop should stop.
I do not think it should stop when `1 < 7`.
I think you should look for a different stop condition.